# MySQL alter table partition by hash month/year - Error . A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Tags: mysql, large-data, database-partitioning

I have a MySQL table (with large data):

```
CREATE TABLE `rider_orders` (
  `id` NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `shift_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `rider_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL
)
```

I want to add partitions month wise (by altering):

```
ALTER TABLE rider_orders
  PARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(date));
```

Comment: What benefit do you expect `PARTITIONing` to provide you?  I have not found anyone that has benefited from Hash partitioning.  Please show us your main queries; we can either provide you with the details for partitioning or show you how indexes can help you without partitioning.

Comment: This question is a bit old, but I stumbled upon it by trying to do the same. I would say that you can do exactly as you suggested in the question. Example from my case where I have table history with datetime column 'time': ALTER TABLE history PARTITION BY HASH(month(time)) PARTITIONS 12;    The big benefit is deletion of records: when the table grows to millions of records, truncate of partition is the fast way of maintaining the size.